# How do I make a bootstrap 3 compatible div dropdown menu with rails 4?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

After some searching I found that I can make a dropdown menu in rails with the select helper but the problem with it is it makes select tags. Firefox doesn't really like select tags and after looking throguh some of the new bootstrap 3 docs I found a way to make dropdowns with div tags as shown [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns).

How would I make something like this and still have it work with rails?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you want is to have your select tag styled as Bootstrap 3 dropdown?

Comment: no. I need to use div tags. The select tag dropdown works find on chrome but not on firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/):

> Select2 is a jQuery based replacement for select boxes. It supports
>   searching, remote data sets, and infinite scrolling of results.

As you will notice it Browser compatibility it "supports" Firefox 10+. Then you can copy the BT3 style if you want.

Comment: That looks pretty good. It's not bootstrap style but at least it's better than that grey blocky box. Thanks.